# Streaming youtube video with server

Tags: php, stream, youtube

[YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) and [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/) are filtered in Iran, and we don't have any access to them, now I'm going to use some video on YouTube and Vimeo and show them to Iranian people.  This means I'm going to make a bridge between Youtube and Iranian visitor of my website, I know PHP but I can't understand how can I do it?

Pipeline of script:
Stream one video file from YouTube with my server that is in America and show it direct to my visitor that is in Iran.

Comment: If you have single video/couple of videos. It would be easier to just download them and host them directly. Creating a proxy for Youtube is not an easy task.

Comment: As Lauri writes, what you're describing is a proxy server. There are already a number of those around - Google for "proxy server"; some of them are written in PHP (again, Google is your friend), and the Apache webserver has mod_proxy which does this too.

Comment: Consider also the existance of http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ a flash program that you can use as *video player* on your pages.